# How do I return a swing event if it not used?

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, mouseevent

[image]

The texts are inside `JPanels` and they are all inside a `JScrollPane`. I have set to catch the `MouseWheelEvent` (scrolling) so when the `Ctrl` key is pressed, and mouse wheel is turned, the texts would zoom in/out (font size is increased/decreased). This has lead to not being able to scroll through the list of fonts anymore unless I point the mouse cursor directly on the scrollbar. I want to know if there is a way to `return` the event when the `Ctrl` key is not held down. Is that possible? I looked through the `MouseWheelEvent` api and didn't find anything useful. Googling didn't give me anything either.

Comment: Not really, this is how `MouseListener`s work generally.  You could try call `Component#dispatchEvent` on the parent component, but you will need to experiment to find which parent will want to respond to the event...

Comment: for (`instanceof`) `TextComponent` placed in `JPanel` to use  `Component c = SwingUtilities.getDeepestComponentAt( e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());` scale from `KeyBindings` mapped to `Ctrl_pressed` + `mouseWheelMoved`, don't forget to test for `e.getWheelRotation()`, last code line should be `myDeepestComponentAt.repaint()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used @MadProgrammer 's comment and got some idea from @okrman 's answer and came up with a better way of doing this. In my solution, I don't need to add two separate event listeners, namely, one to the `JLabel` and the other one to the `JScrollPane`. I use only one event listener on the `JLabel`. The main key here is `Component#dispatchEvent` as mentioned by @MadProgrammer. I just found (rather remembered from my foggy memory) an excellent way to get a hold of the parent `JScrollPane` inside `JLabel`.

Of course, the example I have given here is just an *example*. I have not set the widths or heights for any of the components. The soul purpose of this example is just to show how the problem is solved.

```
public class ParentScrollPane extends JScrollPane {
  public ParentScrollPane() {
    JPanel textContainer = new JPanel();

    // I have multiple labels in a for loop, this is
    // just an example
    JLabel sLabel = new JLabel("SOME LABEL TEXT");
    sLabel.setParent(thisPane);
    textContainer.add(sLabel);

    setViewportView(textContainer);
  }

  // this interface is important and key to the solution
  public interface ParentSetter {
    public void setParent(Component p);
  }

  private JScrollPane thisPane;
}

public class CustomLabel extends JLabel implements ParentScrollPane.ParentSetter {
  public CustomLabel(String text) {
    super(text);

    // one event listener is suffice
    addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener() {
      @Override
      public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
        // if the Ctrl key is down
        if (e.isControlDown()) {
          // then zoom the font in the JLabel
        } else {
          // then scroll the parent scroll pane
          labelParent.dispatchEvent(e);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  // pay very close attention to this and
  // how the parent scroll pane is set here
  @Override
  public void setParent(Component lParent) {
    labelParent = lParent;
  }

  private Component labelParent;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If I did understood you correctly the answer you are looking for should be like this the main idea to  create to different mouse wheel event for your form and your scrollpane. Watch the entire animation you will see your problem is fixed , you can make your manipulations based on this idea

[image]

**you should add below to your fields ;**

```
     public int defaultTextSize = 12;
     boolean ctrlcheck =false;
```

**this is jLabel4 to display CTRL is not pressed  in constructor**

```
   jLabel4.setText("CTRL IS NOT PRESSED");
```

**your scrollpane mouse event should be like this**

```
  private void jScrollPane1MouseWheelMoved(java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent evt) {                                             

int notches = evt.getWheelRotation();

if (notches < 0) {            
    if (ctrlcheck == true) {
        defaultTextSize = defaultTextSize + 3;
        Font zoomfont = new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, defaultTextSize);
        jLabel1.setFont(zoomfont);
        jLabel2.setFont(zoomfont);
        jLabel3.setFont(zoomfont);
        jLabel1.repaint();
        jLabel2.repaint();
        jLabel3.repaint();

    } else {

        System.out.println("CTRL IS NOT PRESSED");

    }
} else {
    if (ctrlcheck == true) {
        defaultTextSize = defaultTextSize - 3;
        Font zoomfont2 = new Font("Monospaced", Font.ITALIC, defaultTextSize);

        jLabel1.setFont(zoomfont2);
        jLabel2.setFont(zoomfont2);
        jLabel3.setFont(zoomfont2);
        jLabel1.repaint();
        jLabel2.repaint();
        jLabel3.repaint();
    }

}


  }
```

**You need FORM Key Released Event Like this**

```
private void formKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                 

    jLabel4.setText("CTRL IS  NOT PRESSED");
    ctrlcheck = false;


}
```

**You need separate event for formMouseWheelMoved**

```
private void formMouseWheelMoved(java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent evt) {                                     

int notches = evt.getWheelRotation();

if (notches < 0) {            
    if (ctrlcheck == true) {
        defaultTextSize = defaultTextSize + 3;
        Font zoomfont = new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, defaultTextSize);
        jLabel1.setFont(zoomfont);
        jLabel2.setFont(zoomfont);
        jLabel3.setFont(zoomfont);
        jLabel1.repaint();
        jLabel2.repaint();
        jLabel3.repaint();

    } else {

        System.out.println("CTRL IS NOT PRESSED");

    }
} else {
    if (ctrlcheck == true) {
        defaultTextSize = defaultTextSize - 3;
        Font zoomfont2 = new Font("Monospaced", Font.ITALIC, defaultTextSize);

        jLabel1.setFont(zoomfont2);
        jLabel2.setFont(zoomfont2);
        jLabel3.setFont(zoomfont2);
        jLabel1.repaint();
        jLabel2.repaint();
        jLabel3.repaint();

      }   
   }   
}
```

**You need Form Keypressed Event as well to check key is still pressed**

```
 private void formKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                

int key = evt.getKeyCode();
if (key == KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL) {

    jLabel4.setText("CTRL IS  PRESSED");
    ctrlcheck = true;

}
}
```